# Can I show SVG images on a VCL application?

Tags: delphi, svg, delphi-10.4-sydney

I know that Delphi 10.4 can show SVG images on Firemonkey apps, but can it do the same for VCL apps ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but a.f.a.i.k,  you will need some extra component for this

Comment: Windows 10 Creators Update introduced native SVG rendering capabilities in its Direct2D API, so if it enough for you to target this Windows version or later, you get it for free from the OS. (And using Direct2D alongside GDI in a Win32 VCL app is easy.)

Comment: Perhaps this one helps: https://github.com/EtheaDev/SVGIconImageList

Comment: Thanks @UweRaabe that looks exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SVGIconImageList project:
https://github.com/EtheaDev/SVGIconImageList
or Skia4Delphi

Comment: Carlo Barazzetta, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35426298)

Comment: Thanks Carlo. Uwe Raabe proposed these same components and I've been using them since then. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Devexpress has good support for SVG.
There is also a collection of SVG Icons if you buy the components.

https://docs.devexpress.com/VCL/dxSVGImage.TdxSVGImage